# payUbiz : payment gateway integration : (incorrectly calculated hash parameter)

Tags: ios, webview, swift3, payment-gateway, payu

Error Scrreenshot attached.

I am facing this error while integrating payUbiz payment gateway for iOS application using WebView.

I am calculating hash code from hash string like this:

```
    let hashValue = "\(key)|\(txnid1)|\(amount)|\(productInfo)|\      (firstname)|\(email)|||||||||||\(Salt)"
    let hash = self.createSHA512(hashValue)

      func createSHA512(toEncrypt:String) -> String
{
    let data = toEncrypt.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
    return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

So, where i am doing mistake in calculating hash?

Answer (score 0):

Your function for calculating hash value looks right.Check your parameters once again, Check from your payUbiz dashboard and paste them in your code.
It might be they are wrongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate **checksumhash** by server side. Paytm provides checksum KIT. I got the full paytm integration from **[here](https://www.studytutorial.in/paytm-payment-gateway-integrating-in-android)** but it is for Android. checksum utility is same for any language.